# '$' confusion on cheerio api

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I have confusion regarding the use of $ sign in the node cheerio api

For example in the code below

```
if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var title, release, rating;
    var json = { title : "", release : "", rating : ""};

    $('.header').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        title = data.children().first().text();            
        release = data.children().last().children().text();

        json.title = title;
        json.release = release;
    })
```

Why is it considered a good practice to set `cheerio.load(html)` value to $? 
Also how are we able to use `$(.header)` without importing jquery?

Comment: `$` is a variable, like any variable you can put anything in it

Comment: cheerio is a version of jquery. So you are importing jquery in a sense

Comment: Cheerio is not a version of jQuery. It's more of a jQuery knock-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheerio implements subset of jQuery. So, now as we know conventionally jQuery uses `$` for namespacing, so developers are used to the $('selector') syntax.

Now, as cheerio implements core functionalities of jQuery and we use it instead of jQuery it makes sense to use `$` as the namespace. It is familiar to developers and the syntaxes are same.

When you import jQuery, the jQuery object is assigned to `$`. When you are using cheerio the cheeerio object is being assigned to `$`.

I wouldn't say it is a good practice. More like it's a convention. Now, I have seen various apps that don't use `$`, they used `jQuery` instead.

For your second question, we are replaceing `jQuery` with `cheerio`. So when you are using `$('.header')` you are not using jQuery you are using cheerio instead.